# Open Source tools for managing Ubuntu Eucalyptus cloud

Tags: open-source, ubuntu, eucalyptus

I have set up an ubuntu-eucalyptus cloud. I just want to know what are the open-source/enterprise tools available (if any) to manage these clouds. For example, how can I monitor the instances in my cloud ? How can i track usage per user/group and bill users accordingly ? how can I create backup of instances etc.

I have searched on the internet but cant find a satisfying article. Please guide .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

management tools I know about for UEC would be
Elastic Fox: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/ElasticFox
and a hosted commercial tool from canonical https://landscape.canonical.com/ plus things that talk EC2 api like scalr or rightscale should work